# symbol used in word is converted to normal text?

Tags: .net, ms-word, symbols, openxml-sdk, wml

In my word I have a symbol (alpha),style as symbol and font size 11. When I read the word in .Net  using openxml(wml),  the symbol is changed to normal text a. How to handle this?

Input
criteria of .70.

```
<w:r w:rsidR="007445E8" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t></w:r><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:t xml:space="preserve">criteria of </w:t></w:r><w:r w:rsidRPr="007445E8" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="Symbol" /><w:highlight w:val="yellow" /></w:rPr><w:t>a</w:t></w:r><w:r xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"><w:rPr><w:rStyle w:val="Symbol" /></w:rPr><w:t> &gt; </w:t></w:r>
```

I except a code to read the symbols as it is in  the word.

Comment: Please show relevant code

Comment: Are you sure the XML that you quote actually corresponds to ".70", or perhaps the first characters of that string ? I ask partly because the XML you have seems to correspond to a piece of text that looks like "a > " (because of the &gt; in the last w:t element of the XML). Maybe the XML you quoted comes from somewhere else in your document?

Comment: s correct the two boxes are alpha(α) and > symbol             this is the input                                                     Before running the multiple regression models, Cronbach’s alpha was calculated for both bar-riers and benefits to determine internal consistency with a α criteria of .70.

Comment: Posting the code that you're using to extract the text would be useful, as @Charlieface says. It might also help if you could copy the relevant part of the document, anonymize it, and put it somewhere accessible such as Dropbox.